# Genexus não está gerando os arquivos para compilação

Tags: genexus

Estou migrando um sistema de `Gx 9` com gerador `VB` para `Gx Evo3`, com gerador `C#`. É meu primeiro contato com a nova versão e estou passando pelo seguinte problema:

Em algumas Transações (não são todas), o **Genexus** especifica e gera o código sem apresentar erros, porém ao compilar apresenta um erro informando a falta do arquivo `bldn[nome da transação].cs` conforme pode ser visto na imagem anexada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já alterei quase todas as configurações do gerador, executando um `build all` em seguida, mas nada resolveu o problema.

A pergunta é: existe alguma configuração que possa resolver o problema? O **Genexus** gera algum log onde eu possa descobrir porque não está gerando os arquivos?

mais detalhes:
Configurações do gerador
[image: Configurações do gerador]

Temos mais de 5mil objetos na KBase, apenas 14 dão esse erro na compilação.

grato

Comment: Poderia colocar o resultado do RE-build All ?Além disso olhar no Visualizador de Eventos para ver se esta ficando algum erro.

Comment: No build all acontece basicamente o que está na primeira imagem,  especifica e gera tudo sem erros, só dá erro na compilação porque não encontra os arquivos. No visualizador de eventos não consta nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente descobri o problema. Pode parecer óbvio para os mais experientes, mas eu estava inserindo os atributos do segundo nível da transação na tela como textboxes, como costumava fazer na versão 9. Mas pelo que percebi os atributos do segundo nível em diante só podem ser inseridos em grids.

Inseri o grid e a transação compilou.